# Javascript href to refresh an iframe not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I made this code to refresh two iframes at the same time after clicking an href image.. It does work on latest google chrome, but it seems it doesn't work on IE8...

here's my code..

```
<script>
function refreshIframe() {
    var ifr = document.getElementsByName('usercount')[0];
    ifr.src = ifr.src;
    var ifr2 = document.getElementsByName('users')[0];
    ifr2.src = ifr2.src;
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:refreshIframe();"><img src="Images/refresh.png"></a>
```

thanks in advance, I hope i could get this work for old browsers.

Comment: Who cares about IE8?

Comment: Sorry about that, but I have a program that uses IE browser, and most of the users have the same thought as yours, so technically they don't update it.

Comment: That also will not work in older version of Chrome. Instead iframe will implement either `contentWindow` or `contentDocument`; detect which is present and call its `.location.reload()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE, `document.getElementsByName(...)[0]` is interpreted as `document.getElementById(...)`, the

```
document.getElementsByName
```

function [Gets a collection of objects based on the value of the NAME or ID attribute.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms536438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So, short answer, it just won't work.

I'd recommend changing all `name="something"` attributes into `class="something"` attributes, and then use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(something)
```

Example:

```
var ifr = document.getElementsByClassName("frame1")[0];
// ^^ this code will get vvthis iframe
<iframe class="frame1" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: so it'll be like `<iframe class="something">` is it?

Comment: hi, i tried it but it seem doesn't refresh the iframes.. If I may could I ask to make a fixed code of mine as shown on my question?

Comment: i had a script error saying that `'frame1' is not defined` as i put into my `<iframe class="frame1">` code.

Comment: @Gelo103097 It accepts a string as an argument, I'll add an example, but it looks like you wrote `frame1` instead of `"frame1"`.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is IE9+. So better `querySelector`.

Comment: now i am having 'Object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: @Gelo103097 That's a problem elsewhere in your code.